# How do you make html elements not blurry

Tags: javascript, html5, html, css

I was making a html game and all the elements are blurry is there a fix to this?
I use css but it makes it blurry

**Code**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width:  75%;
  height: 75%;
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        updateGameArea();
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
        this.hitTop();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
    var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
    if (this.y > rockbottom) {
        this.y = rockbottom;
        this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    }
} // This curly brace was missing.

this.hitTop = function() {
    var skyhigh = 0;          // Top of the window.
    if (this.y < skyhigh) {   // Use less-than to check if you're above.
        this.y = skyhigh;
        this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    }
}
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            return;
        } 
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 50;
        maxGap = 200;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += -1;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
    if (!myGameArea.interval) {myGameArea.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);}

    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
</script>
<br>
<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
<p>Click the ACCELERATE button to start the game</p>
<p>How long can you stay alive? Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air..</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not delete and re-post the same question. If your question isn't getting traction, copying and pasting it will not do better. What you should do instead is to edit your existing question to include more information, like research you've done into the matter or approaches you've tried so far to fix it, along with screenshots of the symptoms.

Comment: If you both assign a % size for your canvas and a fixed size, which one is getting taken in the end? or is it using the `this.canvas.width` but stretches it to fit your % assignment?

Comment: Im guessing its the css streching it but is there a work around

Comment: "Don't stretch your canvas with CSS" sounds like a pretty simple workaround.  I presume you considered setting the native size of your canvas to match the size you want to display it at?

Comment: Is there a way to auto size it?

Answer (score 0):

Crisp edges css may help.
And drawing pixel text from a sprite sheet will be the most crisp vs fillText.

```
   canvas {
       image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;image-rendering: pixelated;image-rendering: crisp-edges;
       border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
       background-color: #f1f1f1;
       width:  75%;
       height: 75%;
       margin: 0;
   }
```